# Getting my toggle to show correctly in laravel livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have a pivot table that links my products and categories together. What I'm trying to do is in my edit page for a product I
have a list of all the categories and each category has a toggle button that will enable or disable that category for that product.

The problem I'm having is that all my categories is set to enabled, but I only have one enabled and the rest is supposed to be disabled

I'm using laravel 8 and livewire

Here is my code

```
    namespace App\Http\Livewire\Products;

    use App\Models\Product;
    use Livewire\Component;
    use App\Models\Category;

    class Edit extends Component
    {

        public Product $product;
        public bool $enabled;

        public $name;
        public $description;

        public function mount()
        {
            $pcPivot = $this->product->categories()->where('product_id', $this->product->id)->exists();

            if($pcPivot === true)
            {
                $this->enabled = true;
            }else{
                $this->enabled = false;
            }

            $this->name = $this->product->name;
            $this->description = $this->product->description;
        }

        public function render()
        {
            $categories = Category::all();

            return view('livewire.products.edit', [
                'categories' => $categories,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

and here is my edit.blade.php

```
    <div>
        <div class="md:grid md:grid-cols-3 md:gap-6">
            <div class="md:col-span-1">
                <div class="px-4 sm:px-0">
                    <h3 class="text-lg font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900">Edit Product</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mt-5 md:mt-0 md:col-span-2">
                <div class="shadow sm:rounded-md sm:overflow-hidden">
                    <form wire:submit.prevent="submit">
                        <div class="px-4 py-5 bg-white sm:p-6">
                            <div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-6">
                                <div class="col-span-3 sm:col-span-2">
                                    <label for="title" class="block text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-gray-700">
                                        Name
                                    </label>
                                    <div class="rounded-md shadow-sm">
                                        <input id="name" wire:model="product.name" class="flex-1 form-input block w-full min-w-0 transition duration-150 ease-in-out sm:text-sm sm:leading-5">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="px-4 py-5 bg-white sm:p-6">
                            <div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-6">
                                <div class="col-span-3 sm:col-span-2">
                                    <label for="description" class="block text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-gray-700">
                                        Description
                                    </label>
                                    <div class="rounded-md shadow-sm">
                                        <textarea id="description" wire:model="product.description" rows="3" class="form-textarea mt-1 block w-full transition duration-150 ease-in-out sm:text-sm sm:leading-5"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="px-4 py-3 bg-gray-50 text-right sm:px-6">
                            <span class="inline-flex rounded-md shadow-sm">
                              <button type="submit" class="inline-flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent text-sm leading-5 font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-500 focus:outline-none focus:border-indigo-700 focus:shadow-outline-indigo active:bg-indigo-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">
                                Update
                              </button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        @include('spacer')

        <div class="md:grid md:grid-cols-3 md:gap-6">
            <div class="md:col-span-1">
                <div class="px-4 sm:px-0">
                    <h3 class="text-lg font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900">Categories</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mt-5 md:mt-0 md:col-span-2">
                <div class="shadow sm:rounded-md sm:overflow-hidden">
                    <table class="min-w-full divide-y divide-gray-200">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <x-th>Title</x-th>
                            <x-th>Enable/Disable</x-th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody class="bg-white divide-y divide-gray-200">
                        @foreach($categories as $category)
                            <tr>
                                <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap">
                                    <div class="flex items-center">
                                        <div class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">
                                            {{ $category->title }}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>

                                <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap">
                                    <div class="mt-1 flex rounded-md">
                                        <span role="checkbox" tabindex="0" aria-checked="false" class="@if($enabled) bg-indigo-600 @else bg-gray-200 @endif relative inline-flex flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-11 border-2 border-transparent rounded-full cursor-pointer transition-colors ease-in-out duration-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true" class="@if($enabled) translate-x-5 @else translate-x-0 @endif inline-block h-5 w-5 rounded-full bg-white shadow transform transition ease-in-out duration-200">
                                               <input id="enabled" type="checkbox" wire:model="enabled" class="invisible">
                                            </span>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [documentation for Livewire, at lifecycle hooks](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/lifecycle-hooks)... you will see that:

```
mount : Runs once, immediately after the component is instantiated, but before render() is called
```

So basically you are getting an "enabled" value once, before rendering the component,then you start rendering it, with that foreach, using the same "enabled" from mount for each item of your dataset.
Consider building your cursor with the enabled value inside for each record.